# Groovy ConfigSlurper Configure Arrays

Tags: arrays, groovy, config

I am trying to create a config that would look something like this:

```
nods = [
    nod {
        test = 1
    },
    nod {
        test = 2
    }
]
```

and then use configSlurper to read it but the "node" objects appear to be null after the read.

Here is my code:

```
final ConfigObject data = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("config.dat").toURI().toURL())
println  data.nods
```

and the output:

```
[null, null]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It think I resolved it this way:

```
config {
   nods = [
      ['name':'nod1', 'test':true],
      ['name':'nod2', 'test':flase]
   ]
}
```

And then using it like:

```
config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("config.groovy").text)
for( i in 0..config.config.nods.size()-1)
    println config.config.nods[i].test
```

Hope this helps someone else!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when using ConfigSlurper when doing this sort of thing.
For example your solution will actually produce the following output:

```
true
[:]
```

If you look carefully you will notice that there is a typo on the second array value **flase** instead of **false**

The following:

```
def configObj = new ConfigSlurper().parse("config { nods=[[test:true],[test:false]] }")
configObj.config.nods.each { println it.test }
```

should produce the correct result:

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to parse with ConfigSlurper something like this:

```
config {sha=[{from = 123;to = 234},{from = 234;to = 567}]}
```

The array "sha" was far from what expected.
To get "sha" as an array of ConfigObjects I used a helper:

```
class ClosureScript extends Script {
    Closure closure

    def run() {
        closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        closure.delegate = this
        closure.call()
    }
}
def item(closure) {
    def eng = new ConfigSlurper()
    def script = new ClosureScript(closure: closure)
    eng.parse(script)
}
```

this way I get an array of ConfigObjects:

```
void testSha() {
    def config = {sha=[item {from = 123;to = 234}, item {from = 234;to = 567}]}
    def xx = item(config)
    assertEquals(123, xx.sha[0].from)
}
```